# TabBar in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I building my first Windows Phone App, and i saw something really nice on one of the apps, i add a screenshoot of this:

[image]

The description is:
green - icons
blue - textbox
yellow - pages

And it is something like panorama , but here the icons(with the text) are in the top all the time, and, and press one of them the jump(with animation) to the chosen page, and of course if the user swipe on the page it move to the next page and the icons are get highlighted.

it's something like UITabBarController, and i want to know how i implement this control? it's some thing build in, if yes what is name? Or any good tutorial how to build it.

thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need built-in control called [Pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941098%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

You can change Header template to put an icon in it:

```
 <controls:Pivot x:Name="pivot"
                    Title="{Binding Name}"          
        <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPannel>
                    <Image Source="your icon path">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </StackPannel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```